# XSL recusrsive linking tree with root

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is a XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="*[parent::*]">
  <xsl:param name="pPath"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$pPath"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vValue" select="normalize-space(text()[1])"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$vValue"/>
  <br/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
    <xsl:with-param name="pPath" select="concat($pPath, $vValue, ': ')"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

when appliedon this XML:

```
<ItemSet>
<Item>1
 <iteml1>1.1</iteml1>
 <iteml1>1.2</iteml1>
</Item>
<Item>2
  <iteml1>2.1
    <iteml2>2.1.1</iteml2>
   </iteml1>
</Item>
</ItemSet>
```

the result is :

```
1
1: 1.1
1: 1.2
2
2: 2.1
2: 2.1: 2.1.1
```

what should i add to it so i can have a link on every elemet of that tree as example :

```
<a href="1">1</a>
<a href="1">1</a> : <a href="1/1.1">1.1</a>
<a href="1">1</a> : <a href="1/1.2">1.2</a>
<a href="2">2</a>
<a href="2">2</a> : <a href="2/2.1">2.1</a>
<a href="2">2</a> : <a href="2/2.1">2.1</a> : <a href="2/2.1/2.1.1">2.1.1</a>
```

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to deal with recursivity for doing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[parent::*]">
      <xsl:variable name="curr-id" select="generate-id()" />
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*[parent::*]">
        <xsl:variable name="curr-sub-id" select="generate-id()" />
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*[parent::*]">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text()[1])"/>
                <xsl:if test="generate-id() != $curr-sub-id">
                    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text()[1])"/>
        </a>
        <xsl:if test="generate-id() != $curr-id">
            <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <br/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```